# How to customize numeric keyboard in Android using ReactNative TextInput

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React-Native (v 0.66.3) [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) to Android to set numeric values, but I would like to find a way to remove the dot button and to have a more accurate keyboard, just to positive numeric values without decimals.

This is the result expected:

[image]

And the code used to the first approach is:

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType="numeric"
  returnKeyType="done"
  ...
/>
```

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to remove the dot then use keyboardType='number-pad"

Comment: I'm not sure if it is an error, but with `number-pad` the aspect is exactly the same.